# Two CSS container divs vertically aligned filling screen 50/50 (media query)

Tags: css, media-queries

I have two containers that are ok on desktop, but on my iPhone I want both vertically filling the screen 50/50 [like this example](http://postimg.org/image/w2gofci5r/).

I want to use the CSS media query in this case for iPhone in particular, which is already visible in the CSS below. I'm having difficulties figuring out how to get those containers right, so both will display an image 50% vertically each and automatically fits it in full width. How do I get these containers as such? Here are the HTML and CSS:

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto !important;
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#container2 {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto !important;
  padding-top 200px;
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.buddy {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 360px;
  height: 360px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: hand;
}

.buddy2 {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 360px;
  height: 360px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: hand;
}

.avatar {
  background: #fff;
  width: 340px;
  height: 340px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-size: 100% auto !important;
  background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { 

/* iPhone media query */
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="buddy" style="display: block;"><div class="avatar" background-image: url(http://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/1111/large/feline-influenza-all-about-cat-flu-5239fffd61ddf.jpg)"></div></div>
    <div class="buddy"><div class="avatar" style="display: block; background-image: url(http://stylonica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Cat-cats-32040775-1440-900.jpg)"></div></div>  
    <div class="buddy"><div class="avatar" style="display: block; background-image: url(http://cbsnews2.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/r/2014/04/15/4ea65e0b-4b11-43d8-9751-1a52f7a9fc3a/thumbnail/620x350/75a030bb4fb3f6576ddaa6e44371d0f1/cat-istock-000025213483.jpg)"></div></div>  
    <div class="buddy"><div class="avatar" style="display: block; background-image: url(http://cdn.inquisitr.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/BnYHSYlIYAAn9gj-1.png)"></div></div>  
  </div>
  
    <div id="container2">
    <div class="buddy2" style="display: block;"><div class="avatar" background-image: url(http://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/1111/large/feline-influenza-all-about-cat-flu-5239fffd61ddf.jpg)"></div></div>
    <div class="buddy2"><div class="avatar" style="display: block; background-image: url(http://stylonica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Cat-cats-32040775-1440-900.jpg)"></div></div>  
    <div class="buddy2"><div class="avatar" style="display: block; background-image: url(http://cbsnews2.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/r/2014/04/15/4ea65e0b-4b11-43d8-9751-1a52f7a9fc3a/thumbnail/620x350/75a030bb4fb3f6576ddaa6e44371d0f1/cat-istock-000025213483.jpg)"></div></div>  
    <div class="buddy2"><div class="avatar" style="display: block; background-image: url(http://cdn.inquisitr.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/BnYHSYlIYAAn9gj-1.png)"></div></div>  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can check out the code and adjust it here http://jsfiddle.net/zu2q9rh4/1/

Comment: to begin you should  fix your HTML Markup here: 
    `<div class="avatar" background-image: url(http://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/1111/large/feline-influenza-all-about-cat-flu-5239fffd61ddf.jpg)"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

In order for your containers to fill the screen, you have to use `width:100%` and you will add that in your media queries. This will span your containers horizontally.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { 

#container, #container2{
width:100%;
}

}
```

If you want your containers to each be 50% of the screen height, you can either find out the screen size of the device and set each container's height to half of that, or you can wrap a container around your containers and set the children containers to be half of the parent container's height.

```
<div id="parentContainer">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <div id="container2"></div>
</div><!--end parentContainer-->

#parentContainer{
height:500px;
}
#container, #container2{
height:50%; //this will be 50% of the parent container
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've put both containers in the parent container with your code. It almost works, alignment seems good now. But it still won't fill the screen (see result http://postimg.org/image/ensof32z7/). How can that be fixed?

Comment: set the width to 100%

Comment: Did that `@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { 

#parentContainer{
height:500px;
}
#container, #container2{
height:50%;
width: 100%;
}`

Comment: But when I set it to width 100% the block goes to the left. See http://postimg.org/image/ph68yb0gj/

Comment: set `.avatar` to `width:100%` as well

Comment: Doesn't change a lot. Something seems to be messing with it. If put all the code on a live snippet, so you can see it yourself http://jsfiddle.net/zu2q9rh4/1/

Comment: I can tell this is your first time with media queries. Where did you get this code? You have to adjust a lot of properties, like margin, padding, position, in your media queries. I did most of the work for you. I added different colored borders around the elements so you can see which ones you need to fix. http://jsfiddle.net/zu2q9rh4/6/

Comment: Ok, thanks. Tried the code, but now it only displays one container somewhere on the left. So it seems something is really not in place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66133/discussion-between-josan-iracheta-and-user1607016).